# How to disable selected table cell highlight after returning from Detail View (Back Segue)

Tags: uitableview, swift

I am having problem with my table view cell. I can't disable the highlight of table cell selection after returning from detail view to main table view using segue with embedded navigation controller. The table cell is still selected. I don't want the table cell selection to be disable when I click one of them to show the detail. I only want to disable them after I returning back from detail view.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I got it now. I solved like this. It's simple theory.

> **We just deselect it when we select the row**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Why a question mark after `tableView`? It is of type `UITableView` not `UITableView?`.

Answer (score 4):

You could also disable cell selection highlighting:

```
import Foundation

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
  {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
  {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir.I really appreciate your help.I can't disable my table cell selection.i only want to hide the highlight after i select one of the cell and coming back from detail.

Comment: This will actually just disable the highlighting - selecting would still work.

Answer (score 4):

The way I like to do it, if you have single selection enabled is to use the **viewDidAppear** Method. That way the user can see the deselection animation when he returns to the tableView.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    if let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedRow, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for cooperating to the answer

Comment: I think you should do this in `viewWillAppear`, otherwise the deselection animation begins after the view controller appears and seems a little late.

Comment: This solution is similar to Notes app. For me, this looks more elegant compared to making highlight disappear right after user tap the cell.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for Swift3 :**

It will allow selection and this is the fix for swift 3.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
```

Should suffice in override func awakeFromNib() too :)

I got a fatal error when adopting the above code.

Comment: This is fine, but it does not show anything to the user about the cell that he/she has selected

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: why answered the question which already same as yours? If you have better solution, you are welcomed to edit.